# Adding a variable to a javascript url call

Tags: javascript, variables, url

I want to add a web traffic analysis tool to my site.

To call it, I have to place the following in each page I want to track in my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analysisTool.js?idtag=123456789&orderid=random"></script>
```

The idtag 123456789 is the tag id assigned to my site

And orderid will be a random number to each page I want to track (it is the way the tool works)

As I don't want to edit the pages if I ever need to change this orderid, I have created myjs.js with:

```
var uid = Math.floor(Math.random()*(100000000-0))+0;
```

And then, I am doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_includes/myjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analysisTool.js?idtag=123456789& orderid ="+uid></script>
```

But this must be a wrong way to do it because in the browser tools, in the net chapter, I cannot see the orderid.

I’ve checked the path to myjs.js is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the script-tag completely with javascript. You cant use javascript variables like that in the HTML page.

If you want to add a script-tag dynamicly use this script:

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); //create new tag
script.src = "http://analysisTool.js?idtag=123456789&orderid=" + uid;//set the url with your id
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);//append the scripttag
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at jQuery [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

I think it could solve your problem:

> By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a >timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser >downloads the script each time it is requested.

And please note that "document.write" also works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to access uid in a wrong way (in the src attribute). It needs to be in a script context so your only option is to add the script dinamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_includes/myjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://analysisTool.js?idtag=123456789& orderid ="+uid);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

please add this js declaration dynamic in your myjs.js. Means create the script tag through your javascript code.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    var uid = Math.floor(Math.random()*(100000000-0))+0;
    script.src = 'http://analysisTool.js?idtag=123456789&orderid=' + uid;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```